# WP theme search results and Algolia results simultaneously

Tags: wordpress, search, algolia

I have installed and set up the Algolia WP plugin. The instant search function works, however it displays both the Algolia search results list and my theme's native search results list. They sit on top of each other.

I thought that Algolia hid the themes search results and only showed the Algolia results?

How do I fix this?

[Example here](http://52.209.186.138/dwqa-questions/)

Comment: It's better to ask plugin author in support tab of the wordpress plugin repo.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin author here,

The plugin replaces the search.php template file with a custom template shipped with the plugin that you can customize by following this guide: https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/customize-search-page.html

My guess is that in your case, your theme injects search results via javascript, which still happens even after the plugin overrides the template.

You could try to disable that logic.

Could you also send us a link to your theme so that we can confirm our assumption?

Comment: Ok, I will have a look at that thanks. The link to my website is here: http://52.209.186.138 and the theme I am using is here: http://seventhqueen.com/themes/kleo/